# Позиционирование фона

Tags: html, css

В блоке задается повторяющийся фон

```
aside{
       background: transparent url(../images/aside_background.png) repeat-y;
}
```

нужно, чтобы фон начинался не от верха блока, а чуть ниже, но задание отступа через `background-position` смещения фона не дает

```
background: transparent url(../images/aside_background.png) 0px 20px repeat-y;
```

точнее говоря. смещение по оси х срабатывает

```
background: transparent url(../images/aside_background.png) 20px 0 repeat-y;
```

а по оси y, то есть, собственно, то, что и требуется - нет.
Я так понимаю, что причина в том, что задано repeat-y - есть какой-нибудь способ добиться нужного смещения фона при этом?

И еще вопрос по фону, можно ли каким-либо образом сделать так, чтобы фон не доходил до низа блока, а также задать снизу какое-то расстояние, которое будет оставаться от фона до нижнего края блока?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При repeat-x/y картинка повторяется в два направления одновременно, что по сути исключает возможность начала этого повторения в какой-то определенной точке.

Выход только один - сделать доп. контейнер, где внутри вставлен Ваш элемент с фоном.

Примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/KbMdZ/

Comment: да, спасибо, я уже по такому же принципу - через вложенный блок - и сделала.